# Trying to launch Microsoft Edge Chromium in a new process for Java App-V

Tags: java, microsoft-edge, chromium, appv

We are trying to migrate from internet explorer to Microsoft Edge chromium. We have a couple applications which require Java, we used to have internet explorer web application shortcuts using the "-noframemerging" paramater so we can sideload Java App-V for certain applications.

I can't seem to find a way to get this to work in Microsoft Edge Chromium, the problem is if a user already has a Microsoft Edge chromium window open and he opens the web application shortcut which require java, java app-v won't be loaded cause it will open in the same process that already exist.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Are you trying to isolate applications in each process? If yes then you can try to check --site-per-process command-line switch. It enforces a one-site-per-process security policy: * Each renderer process, for its whole lifetime, is dedicated to rendering pages for just one site. * Thus, pages from different sites are never in the same process. * A renderer process's access rights are restricted based on its site. * All cross-site navigations force process swaps. * <iframe>s are rendered out-of-process whenever the src= is cross-site.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to isolate applications in each process then I suggest you can have a test with **--site-per-process** command-line switch.

You can refer to the steps below to apply the command line switch.

1. Create a shortcut of the MS Edge Chromium browser.
2. Then try to right-click on the shortcut and go to properties.
3. Go to the Shortcut tab.
4. In the target field, try to add --site-per-process after the path of Edge exe. make sure there is one space between the path and this argument.

[image]

5. Click on the OK button.

You can try to test this approach and let us know about your testing results.

Answer (score 0):

Start Edge with a separate profile ( --profile-directory )
Create the profile folder before starting Edge.